# Wordpress - Styles Got Messed Up

Tags: wordpress

Hey so I started using Wordpress and am currently using the Seed Prod plugin. When I finished my site, I cleared the cache and opened it in incognito mode. So this is clean. And you know what, it looks good.

But a few days or weeks rolls by and suddenly, when I access the site again, the styles are all out of wack and it's shifted to the left. And I am super confused as to why this happened as there was no changes to it whatsoever. In order to fix this, I cleared the cache and it went back to normal. Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix this?

Comment: it seems your style is not loading on page load. Can you tell me the path of your style sheet.

Comment: why do you say on page load? I don't even know where my stylesheets is located on wordpress. I just used the UI to make a site. I cleared the cache and when I loaded it up, it looks fine. But without any changes, suddenly a few weeks later it shifted to the left

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok found out what the issue was. Before I used SeedProd, I had published a page under the same URL. I'd figure once I create my SeedProd page, it would just replace it, but instead, both kinda loads up. Like it loaded up stuff from my original page and it kept getting a 499. After turning that page to private, my SeedProd page no longer had issues.